# Splitting a text file to different variables C#

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a text file that has information for courses and I need to split them up to be displayed in different list boxes in C#. An example of the text file is below:

BIO    Biology    45
CHE    Chemistry    50

What I want to do is to be able to split each of them up and display them in separate list boxes. There are tabs between each of the sections.

Thank you

Comment: Ummm... `String.Split`? Can you be a *bit* more specific?

Comment: Okay, you exposed what you want. Now please share what's your actual question and what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
using(StremReader sr = new StreamReder(filePath))
{
  while(!sr.EndOfStream)
  {
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    string[] items = line.Split(' ');

    listBox0.Items.add(items[0]);
    listBox1.Items.add(items[1]);
    listBox2.Items.add(items[2]);
   }
}
```

for example

`line = "BIO Biology 45";`

`items[0]="BIO"` and `items[1]="Biology"` and `items[2]="45"`